# Control Source code access in OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

I have a drupal site running on OpenShift. I am able to access the source code using ssh. How can i make other people in a development team access specific portions of the source code and not be able to fork the whole project. If not how can i access a git gui for openshift akin to bitbucket or github?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how OpenShift work but probably you have option to add collaborators. If not you can create GitHub group with your code and then add your collaborators to it with write access. Then they can push directly to this repo without forking and sending pull requests.

Comment: Openshift uses git as source control. I have heard of git hooks let me see if they can achieve what I want.